# get overlay control only for some *.geojson objects

Tags: leaflet, controls, overlay, geojson

I read and format my feature collection with:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  if (feature.properties.popupContent == null)
       {return null}
       else
       {return layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent)};
 };

function MarkerStyle (feature,latlng) {
  if (feature.properties.markerSymbol == null)
  {return L.marker(latlng);}
  else
  {return L.marker(latlng, {icon:  L.icon({iconUrl:
                               feature.properties.markerSymbol})});}
  };

var daten =  $.ajax(overlay).done(function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    daten = L.geoJson(data, 
            {pointToLayer: MarkerStyle,
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);
    return daten});

L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

There are points and polygons in my feature collection.
How can I add an overlay control ONLY for the polygons? I tried with filter, but nothing worked. Thanks for reading the code!

Gruss, wonk

Thank you,
I now understand, that the filter function is only used, to reduce the features, which are displayed on the map. Right?
This is not my intention.

I want a control for EACH polygon in the feature collection. I now tried:

```
  var polygons =  L.geoJSON();
  var overlayLayers = null; 
  var controls = L.control.layers(baseLayers,overlayLayers).addTo(map);

  function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    if(feature.properties.control != null)
        {polygons.addData(feature)
                .bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
         polygons.addTo(map);
         polygon = polygons;
        controls.addOverlay(polygon,feature.properties.control);
        polygon = null;
        };
  if (feature.properties.popupContent == null)
       {return null}
            };
```

This works so far, I get a control for each polygon. But the polygons only disappear, if I deactivate ALL polygon-controls. I want to deactivate single polygons!

Gruss, wonk

Comment: Please add the code for a filter that you tried, even if it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I have now found a solution for the task:

```
var overlayLayers = null; 
var controls = L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlayLayers).addTo(map);

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    var ObjektLayer = L.geoJSON();
        ObjektLayer.addData(feature);
    if (feature.geometry.type == "Polygon" )
        {if (feature.properties.control != null)
            {controls.addOverlay(ObjektLayer,feature.properties.control);
            };
        if (feature.properties.popupContent != null)
            {ObjektLayer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
            };
        ObjektLayer.addTo(map);  
        };
 };
```

Gruss, wonk